# Interpreting crash at nopl

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-3

Using swift I have a reproducible crash that occurs when I try to run a function a second time on my watch app. Whenever the crash happens, Xcode gives me the `EXC_BREAKPOINT` as a `nopl` command in the `HKHealthStore` thread. From what I understand `nopl` is no operation and literally does not do anything. So I don't know how I should be interpreting a crash during a `nopl`. Is it possible Xcode is wrong about the breakpoint? Might it actually be breaking at the start of the next command?

Comment: Please include the actual code causing the issue and try setting up an exception breakpoint to see the actual exception.

Comment: I haven't been able to key into where the error has actually occurred. However, I attempted to ask the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664116/healthkit-crashing-when-pulling-heart-rate-on-second-call-after-working-on-first) with code before and got no responses. So I was hoping a more general question would be easier to answer while still pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: How would it be easier to answer a generic question about a specific debugging issue than to answer the actual question with the code included? Moreover, you shouldn't ask the same question twice. If you don't get an answer, try improving the question through editing and if you feel it cannot be improved, but has to be rewritten, delete it and ask a new question afterwards. However, in this case the new question is even less likely to get an answer than the old one.

Comment: Because the specific question requires an answerer to understand my code (assuming I even have all the code necessary) without being able to run it. Where as someone who knows assembly code well or has had experience with a similar crash could explain how a crash at a `nopl` is in fact possible without having to know anything about my specific situation. I might have not been clear about what I'm looking for but it is not for someone to debug my code off the little info provided but rather to clarify how a crash could occur at a `nopl`.